# C# combat with objects

Tags: c#

To familiarize myself with the basics of programming I'm attempting to make a short, simple RPG. I'm probably not going to be doing anything the most efficient way, nor am I looking to. I am, however, looking to make everything functional.

For this game, from my understanding  I should use classes for players and enemies and create objects for each one to make it easier on myself. However, this made things harder when it came to combat. In my `playerAttack` function, I figured that since the player doing the attacking isn't always going to be the same player, I would need to use that specific player (in this case, *player1*) since the stats would be different. The same goes for enemies. You can see my logic in the line I commented out.

Now the error I'm getting there is that *player1* and *badguy1* don't exist in the current context, which I assume is because they aren't initialized within that function itself. But I'm pretty sure I don't WANT them to be initialized there.

So I suppose I have two questions :

1. how do I fix my current error?
2. how am I supposed to do combat when the combatants will be changing all the time? Should I not be using objects?

Thanks for any help.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sim
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Player player1 = new Player();
            player1.currentHP = 30;
            player1.maxHP = 30;
            player1.atp = 10;
            player1.dfp = 5;


            Enemy badguy1 = new Enemy();
            badguy1.currentHP = 30;
            badguy1.maxHP = 30;
            badguy1.atp = 8;
            badguy1.dfp = 4;

        }
        public void playerAttack()
        {
            int enemyDamage;
           // enemyDamage = player1.atp - badguy1.dfp; 
        }
     public class Player
    {
       public int currentHP;
       public int maxHP;
       public int atp;
       public int dfp;

    }
    public class Enemy
    {
        public int currentHP;
        public int maxHP;
        public int atp;
        public int dfp;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `player` and `enemy` parameters of `playerAttack`:

```
public void playerAttack(Player player, Enemy enemy)
{
    int enemyDamage = player.atp - enemy.dfp;
    ...
}
```

then when you call `playerAttack` you can pass whatever appropriate to it. For example:

```
Player player1 = new Player();
player1.currentHP = 30;
player1.maxHP = 30;
player1.atp = 10;
player1.dfp = 5;

Enemy badguy1 = new Enemy();
badguy1.currentHP = 30;
badguy1.maxHP = 30;
badguy1.atp = 8;
badguy1.dfp = 4;

playerAttack(player1, badguy1);
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems pretty clean. Now how would I go about updating the enemy's hp after the attack? Obviously I would do a currentHP = maxHP - enemyDamage to calculate what it would be, but then wouldn't I have to return that value somehow?

Comment: You can change it directly in `playerAttack`, like this: `enemy.currentHP = enemy.maxHP - enemyDamage;`. You don't have to return anything from `playerAttack`, the change to `enemy` inside `playerAttack` will reflect to `badguy1` outside `playerAttack`, because the two variables `enemy` and `badguy1` point to the same object.

Comment: Okay cool. Now I tried calling playerAttack(player1, badguy1) in the code of my attack button (I'm using forms), and I got the same "current context" error from before. I'm not getting it where I was originally though, which is great.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize them globally

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Player player1 = new Player();
    player1.currentHP = 30;
    player1.maxHP = 30;
    player1.atp = 10;
    player1.dfp = 5;


    Enemy badguy1 = new Enemy();
    badguy1.currentHP = 30;
    badguy1.maxHP = 30;
    badguy1.atp = 8;
    badguy1.dfp = 4;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
    public void playerAttack()
    {
        int enemyDamage;
        enemyDamage = player1.atp - badguy1.dfp; 
    }
 public class Player
{
   public int currentHP;
   public int maxHP;
   public int atp;
   public int dfp;

}
public class Enemy
{
    public int currentHP;
    public int maxHP;
    public int atp;
    public int dfp;

}
}
```

This way, you can actually call them on anywhere within the class.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it would work. Is it really a good idea to make everything global though? That would be a looooot of globals. I don't know if that's common practice or not

Comment: @codingnewbierc It's not a good idea, but it depends on your intended use. 

If you want you could just use parameter passing as stated by the other answer.